# Kotlin extension-method overriding

Tags: kotlin, overriding, extension-methods

I can write code like this:

```
open class A{
    open fun String.q(){
        print("a")
    }
    open fun z(){
        val s:String=""
        s.q()
    }
}

class B : A(){
    override fun String.q() {
        print("b")
    }
    override fun z(){
        val s:String=""
        s.q()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a : A = B()
    a.z()
}
```

And this normally works. Even more, if I remove "overriden" modifier from String.q() in B class, compiler says it's wrong. I've heard that I cannot override extension-methods in Kotlin. Is it bug or some kind of feature?

Comment: Maybe I've understood smth wrong in theoretical part?

Comment: Its extension in a local scope, extensions are synthetic-sugar, it is represented as `open fun q(a: String)` in the bytecode. You can override this inside a scope here is B class. While if you do the same in the top-level you won't be able to, because at one file only 1 same name extension function can lie, and you cannot extend a file like a class.